# Does Firebase support validating a pre-existing facebook access token?

Tags: firebase

Suppose, for the sake of argument, that I already have a facebook access token for a user of my application. In that case, I don't really need to go through Firebase's whole auth.login("facebook") process, I really just want a trusted server to make sure this is a real access token (e.g. by making a GET request to "https://graph.facebook.com/me" with it) and then to set the Firebase user ID appropriately. Can Firebase do this?

Comment: It is technically possible, but not through a documented API.

Comment: I'd be cool with an undocumented approach for now, although you guys should consider an official API so people can build full Facebook SDK apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Simple Login was recently updated to support logging in with an existing Facebook access token.

This means that you can integrate directly with then native Facebook JS SDK in your application, and then pass that Facebook access token to Firebase Simple Login (skipping a second pop-up) via:

```
var ref = new Firebase(...);
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(ref, function(error, user) { ... });
auth.login('facebook', { access_token: '<ACCESS_TOKEN>' });
```

See the `access_token` option on https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-facebook.html for more information.